# How to fix gTTS Unable to find token python error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-text-to-speech, gtts

Im trying to create a virtual assistant but I cant get the gTTS working (google text to speech) working and I cant seem to fix it

```
import os
import time
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS

def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text = text, lang="en")
    filename = "voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)

speak("hello i am bob")
```

**This is the error im getting**

```
File "/Users/danielcaminero/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/SJ-000/pyda/script.py", line 13, in <module>
    speak("hello i am bob")
  File "/Users/danielcaminero/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/SJ-000/pyda/script.py", line 10, in speak
    tts.save(filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 295, in save
    self.write_to_fp(f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 251, in write_to_fp
    prepared_requests = self._prepare_requests()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtts/tts.py", line 194, in _prepare_requests
    part_tk = self.token.calculate_token(part)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtts_token/gtts_token.py", line 28, in calculate_token
    seed = self._get_token_key()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtts_token/gtts_token.py", line 58, in _get_token_key
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unable to find token seed! Did https://translate.google.com change?
```

Comment: also am getting this if someone can fix it

"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'playsound'"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, until I upgrade gTTS-token

```
pip install gTTS-token --upgrade
```

And let me tell you as well that I have a Windows machine in which I run a Linux terminal. In that case I couldn't make it work (Nevertheless try it if this is your case).
Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

There was an [ISSUE with gtts](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/232) depending on the version you were using that returned this *token seed* error.

The ISSUE has been closed and it seems updating go **gtts version 2.1.2** and newest resolved the problem.

*Obs: I personally used 2.2.1 today and everything worked as expected.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows.
I've just uninstalled the module gtts and installed it again(now having the last version of it)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).